# C++ SDL x and y axis on SDL_Rect

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm working with the SDL library for C++.
When I change the `x` and `y` values, I can get my rectangle to move around, but not in the manner I'm expecting.
For example, it moves down with a larger `y` coordinate.
Why is this?

```
//Render rectangle (xPos, yPos, width, height) using constants.
SDL_Rect fillRect = { S_WIDTH / 4, S_HEIGHT / 4, S_WIDTH / 2, S_HEIGHT / 2 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Coordinate system in SDL is top-left (that is, `(0, 0)` is placed in the top-left corner).
Because of that, `x` goes from left to right, `y` from top to down.
Greater the value of `y`, (let me say) *lower* the position of the rectangle.
That's all. It works as expected. It's a matter of what you were expecting and that was wrong.